# How to know when window is opening first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal dialog window. Is there any event (or way) how to know when window is opened first time (not refresh, not postBack etc)? It is necessary for clearing cookie.

Comment: @Andrew Peacoc,I need to clear cookie, say, with name "SelectedNode" when window is opened or closed

Comment: Why not just have a JS flag variable that indicates whether it's been opened before? Initialize it to `false`, then flip it to `true` when the modal dialog is opened. Page refreshes and postbacks will reload the page and set the variable back to false on its own.

Comment: @Zhihao, i need do it on the modal dialog window event. I don't know from where this window will be opened.

Comment: @andDaviD can you set the flag as a global variable (for the page)? Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but from what I'm imagining you only need to know *when* the event was triggered, and not from *where*.

Comment: use sessions, set some session variable first time and check if set it mean reloaded or postback else first visit

Comment: @Zhihao, I edited one control, that is located in one microsoft dll. It consist of 3 elements. One of them is a button which opens new dialog window. I redirect the url of this button to my own window. So, when this window is opening I need to clear cookie. But this control from microsoft dll can be created anywhere on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are the one coding the 'opening window' behavior. Why not store some variable (flag) that indicated whether the windows has been opened before or not? This can be a normal veriable or a session, cookie, local storage, etc. for long term storage.

Comment: I don't know from where this window will be opened. And the instance of this modal dialog isn't created by me. It is created in one microsoft dll.

Comment: Well...there must be some point where you can interact with the window or where you tell it to open. Otherwise...your're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If the just the cookie is your concern,

then change the cookie key(if you want to discard old cookie) or 
don't set any expiration time for you cookie(if you want it not be sent with next fresh request) as default is session